# Using TFS with VS2003

Tags: .net, visual-studio

As per Microsoft Pattern & Practice blog its recommended to use MSBee.

To build a .NET 1.1 applications with Team Build

• Upgrade your .NET 1.1 solutions to .NET 2.0. You can do this by opening the solution in Visual Studio 2005 and running the Conversion Wizard, or by running devenv projectname /upgrade

• Ensure that the .NET 1.1 Software Development Kit (SDK) is installed on your build server.

• Download and install MSBuild Extras from http://www.codeplex.com/MSBee

• Download BuildingFx11inTB.targets from http://blogs.msdn.com/gautamg/attachment/578915.ashx

• Check out the build type from source control that will build your .NET 1.1 project.

• Copy BuildingFx11inTB.targets to the directory containing the build type and check the file into source control.

• Edit TFSBuild.proj file:

• Import the BuildingFx11inTB.targets file:

•Add a property defining the CSharp targets:

CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets=$(ProgramFiles)\MSBuild\MSBee\MSBuildExtras.Fx1_1.CSharp.targets
       
•Check TFSBuild.proj into source control.

Can this be done without upgrading to net 2.0. we have to stay with VS2003 and trying to  use TFS.  have a HUGE app in VS2003 (1000 pages )

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use ? Because this guideline looks to be for TFS 2008, not 2010...

Comment: Locked in to .NET 1.1? Sounds horrible.

Comment: So, if you have a huge app written in an obsolete version of .NET, then maybe upgrading would be a Good Thing to Do. That upgrade isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: You can always hand-write the csproj files :). No seriously, as I also mentioned on a very similar post on MSDN Social today, upgrading is something you will want to do anyway. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/457f8524-043e-49db-ae10-fe5e18dc9e07

Comment: @DBM: locked in TFS? Sounds horrible. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the projects to 2.0 is done as you need MsBuild based project files. Visual Studio 2003 uses the 'old style' project files and these aren't compatible with Team Build and MsBuild.

Upgrading your projects is the easiest way to get those files, as the upgrade process will translate them for you. By then using the MSBee targets you explain MsBuild you want to build using the .NET 1.1 SDK.

You can create these project files yourself if you'd like, it's a lot of work. But that way you don't need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2005. But any changes made to the 2003 projects need to be reflected in the MsBuild version of your projects as well. One solution would be to generate the MsBuild projects on demand just before invoking MsBuild. I haven't seen that done yet, but investing in a project conversion tool might solve your issue as well.

Another solution you could try, is to simply keep your solutions and projects as-is and create one msbuild.proj file which does nothing more than invoke `devenv /build YourSolution.sln` using the [Community MsBuild Tasks](http://www.loresoft.com/projects/msbuildtasks/default.aspx). That way you don't need to upgrade anything, but you loose out on a lot of the features of Team Build (which won't work for 1.1 projects anyways). You can use the [Microsoft SCC Pprovider for TFS](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bce06506-be38-47a1-9f29-d3937d3d88d6) to connect Visual Studio 2003 directly to TFS for source control to prevent having to upgrade to Visual Studio 2005 or newer. There are some issues with invoking devenv directly. Sometimes it will pop-up a dialog box causing your build to hang.